# Is It possible to redirect external graphics card output to onboard hdmi output of my motherboard?

Tags: desktop, desktop-computer, graphics

My recent build has following configuration

```
Motherboard: msi-x570
Graphics card: Nvidia 1660ti
CPU: Ryzen 7 3700x
```

and four monitors attached already

honestly I'm a pc noob

my Graphics card output has 1-hdmi output and 3-DisplayPort output
but I want to utilize one additional HDMI output present on MotherBoard
will it be possible..?

Comment: No you cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

No. The HDMI output of your motherboard is connected to the optional graphics part in the CPU. The 3700X has no such part and thus you cannot use it.

Note that even if you have an chips with both CPU and GPU parts then you would be using the on die one, and not the Nvidia card.

---

To avoid confusion: Two notes:

1. Machines can be designed to use the Nvidia as rendered and the (in your case missing) APU GPU part as output. But that is almost only done in laptops and even then it is usually a bad deal since drivers do not tend to get updated.
2. Some forms of DX12 can use other cards as renderer. No special drivers needed, but you would still need the GPU parts on your APU.

Please note that you can daisy chain DP monitors.

So assuming you have a monitor with both DP in and DP out you could do this:

PC (DP out) ---> Display 1 ---> display 2 --> display 3 ---> display 4

And still have used only one output port.

Downside to that is bandwidth, so chaining four 4k monitors might not be an option. But 4x 1080 screens is not a problem. (or 2x 2k, or ... )